# HDMI Splliter selector

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

Not sure if this forum is the right place to post this. If it isn't it would help me to know the actual place to do so.

So, here's the thing:
I have a computer, a monitor screen and a TV. I want to be able to select which output the video from the computer goes to. I have tried buying the standard HDMI splitter, but all of them are multiple input, one output. My case is one input and multiple outputs.
I'm considering fabricating my own selector since I have some skill with soldering and woodworking (would basically be a wooden box with a switch). I just want to know, how can I fabricate a switch that can switch between the two HDMI channels(which are basically two HDMI cables)

Comment: Pure guess... but perhaps the reason that none exists is that suddenly switching all the connecters, even absolutely simultaneously, upsets the output device.

Comment: The type of switch you're looking for already exists. I am guessing you are simply not using the correct terminology to find it. I typed HDMI Output Selector into google and found results right away.

Comment: Why do you need to switch? You may be able to connect both devices to your graphics card, with HDMI to your TV and DVI to your monitor. You can then switch in the OS multi-monitor configuration. If you need to use HDMI for both, then a splitter would provide a permanent connection to both displays, though generally both displays would need to be the same resolution and refresh rate if both are active at the same time.

Comment: This would probably be a better fit on Hardware Recommendations SE, but it does seem the terminology in the question is off. An "HDMI switch" switches multiple inputs to one output. An "HDMI splitter" takes one input to multiple outputs.  There are also "HDMI matrix"s that allow switching multiple inputs to multiple outputs that can be configured independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular [HDMI connector](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=high_definition_multimedia_interface_hdmi&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction) has [15 lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Cables) on a [19-pin connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:HDMI_Connector_Pinout.svg), so a mechanical switch would be difficult to find. Your best best would be to cannibalize a [DB25 mechanical switch](https://www.google.com/search?q=DB25%20switch), after you confirm you actually have the standard connector and [not a variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Connectors). Keep the total resistance within 85-115 ohms to comply with standard.